# How do I import a package from a file from another package?

Tags: java, compilation, package

I have a class Car that extends Vehicle and that is in package B

Vehicle is in package A

Both files are in different folders

When I compile main, which is not in a package, it does just fine, but I get the value 0 for every variables that were inherited from vehicles when I print a car object after creating it.

When I try to re-compile Car after moving the file Car into the directory it created after compilation, I can't compile it. When it is in the main folder I can compile it for some weird reason.

```
package Car;

import Vehicle.*;

public class Car extends Vehicle
{
  <some code>
}
```

I get the following error:

'cannot find symbol' and 'package does not exist'

Comment: also i didn't use super() for the constructor of the child objects. i tried and it gave me errors (probably because it can't find the package for some reason). i manually created the package btw.

Comment: can you share Vehicle class also

Answer (score 0):

what does your source tree look like? Package names in java begin with a lowercase letter and the classes that go in them with uppercase. e.g.

package mypkg;
class MyClass {}

would be in a folder called mypkg and the java class would be called MyClass.java

To import it in another class you'd use:

import mypkg.MyClass;

Anyway, for the moment, try setting up what you have something like this maybe:

src/
  Vehicle.java
  Car.java

then change make Vehicle.java look something like:

```
public class Vehicle { 
 <your code here>
}
```

and Car.java:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
 <some code>
}
```

then compile.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple: the hierarchy of the folders must match exactly with the hierarchy of the packages. So, assuming src is the folder where all your source files are, the tree should be:

```
src
  Main.java
  Car
    Car.java
  Vehicle
    Vehicle.java
```

To compile all the classes  to the folder classes, you would use the following command (from the src directory):

```
src> javac -d ..\classes Main.java Car\Car.java Vehicle\Vehicle.java
```

And this will create the following files, which also respect the package hierarchy:

```
classes
  Main.class
  Car
    Car.class
  Vehicle
    Vehicle.class
```

You can then execute your main class , still from the src directory, using

```
src> java -cp ..\classes Main
```

Note that placing classes in the default package is a bad practice, and should be avoided. Packages should also be written in lower-case.

Comment: No, you of course don't have to. But since you're moving files, I assumed you weren't using an IDE. An IDE would place the Java files in the appropriate folders automatically, based on the package entered or chosen when creating the class. And it would generate an error if you moved the file to an incorrect folder. Whatever tool you use, you MUST understand the above.